# Best desktop computer option for ROS

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning to buy a new desktop specifically to use ROS and Turtlebot application. Is there a best option to go after. It would be nice to have a machine with Ubuntue and perhaps ROS pre-installed and a graphic card that is going to be the best option for Gazebo and rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62350/best-desktop-computer-option-for-ros/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2013-05-08**:
Gazebo requires more power than rviz, for this reason I would ask this question to http://answers.gazebosim.org too If I were you. One has to be quite careful with graphic cards since not all of them work in ubuntu easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use a [System 76 Leopard Extreme](https://www.system76.com/desktops/model/leox3) as my desktop, and have been very happy with it.  Enough power to run Gazebo and some control code, and zero problems with nVidia video card.  Preinstalled with Ubuntu 12.04.  I also have a [Gazelle Professional laptop](https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/gazp8), which I'm similarly happy with, although it weighs a ton.  The seem to have moved to an Intel graphics card for this, though, rather than the nVidia that I have in mine.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on 2013-05-20**:
Thanks for your reply. I was wondering how much graphic card is needed, the default is 1GB nVidia, is it enough.

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-05-20**:
I've got whatever the default option is, and it's fine.  A faster/better card will let you render more polygons, but the critical thing, IMO, is the closed-source nVidia drivers.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-27**:
I'm quite happy with my System 76 Serval laptop. ZaReazon also makes a good platform as long as they have the discrete graphics cards.